Dilaton and scalar hair
I see that there are many papers for dilaton black hole with the scalar hair. So, what is the difference between dilaton and scalar hair of the black hole?

From a practical point of view, they are just two different scalar fields. One couples to the metric via $e^{2\phi} [ R + ( \nabla \phi )^2 ] $ the other couples to the metric via $( \nabla \psi )^2$.
